# change sidebar on jump link in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, sidebar

I have front page with jump links as a menu.My design require change sidebar when user click on specific jump link in menu.I knew how to handle this if menu consist on pages,posts or categories but i am not sure how to handle this situation with jump link.Please guide me.

Comment: Can you share that page URL? not sure what you mean by jump? link to redirect in same page with target?

Comment: Yes i am talking about navigate on same page using ids.Currently i am working on localhost.

Comment: But still share something which give more idea to help you. share screenshot of page.

Comment: Please check this screenshot.Hope u understand what i am trying to do.

Comment: I do not have access to that site , can you please add screen shot in question?

Comment: i just add screenshot in question.Please check it

Comment: ok so you need like if you click on blog then it should change right sidebar , right?

Comment: I created two sidebars.If user click on blog then get_sidebar('blog'); if user click on any other links then it display get_sidebar('home').In both cases  there is only left sidebar.

Comment: so on click of blog menu , does it not changing page?

Comment: No clicking blog will navigate on same page.

Comment: so page URL will remain same?

Comment: yes Page url will remain same except clicking blog will add "#blog" in the end of the url

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript to change sidebar using #target:

Exemple:

Html:

```
<aside id="widget">
<ul>
<li id="widget1" class="active">Widget 1</li>
<li id="widget2">Widget 2</li>
<li id="widget3">Widget 3</li>
</ul>
</aside>
```

With css show/hide the first widget:

```
#widget li{
display:none;
}
#widget .active{
display:block !important;
}
```

Then with jquery, trigger the show if the href contains a hash:

```
var atarget = $(this).attr('href');
$(document).on('click','#nav a',function(e){
if(atarget.indexOf('#') > -1){
event.preventDefault();
$('#widget li').removeClass('active');
$(atarget).addClass('active');


}
});
```

Comment: Thank your for your reply.I am not looking for hiding any widget.I want to load different sidebars on specific link.

Comment: In that case, you need to register individual widget for each template or you can use widget logic plugin to achieve that. https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/, but your question is about internal links.